# How to convert image to base64 in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, base64

I tried to convert image that uploaded using postman, this is my code to handle image in controller

```js
const foto = req.files.foto;
const fotoName = foto.name;
res.send(fotoName);
```

I need to convert `fotoName` to `base64`, anybody please help me?

Comment: ....please don't do this. There is **nerver** a legitimate reason for storing any more than a few hundred KB in Base64, let alone photos/images/etc.

Comment: can u tell me how,please? i'm really stuck

Comment: `fotoName` is the _name_ of the image file, not its contents, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough it isn't recommendet to do, this is how you would do it

```js
var nameBase64 = Buffer.from(foto.name).toString('base64')
res.send(nameBase64);
```

Keep in mind, **base64 is not a convinient way to save data in f. e. a database**. You **will** encounter huge loading times.

Comment: Is there another way to save image in database using flutter web?

Comment: @Mayati Generally speaking you shouldn't be storing large-binaries (images, files, videos, etc) inside an RDBMS - but if you absolutely have to then you should use your DB's native `varbinary` or "`blob`" type (it depends on what RDBMS you're using).

Answer (score 0):

`base64` is not recommended in database because it may actually increase the loading and processing times. However you can you can try it like this:

```
// Convert the image data to base64
const base64Image = data.toString('base64');

res.send(base64Image);
```

Comment: Is there another way to save inag

Comment: Is there another way to save image to database using fluter web?